# Where to download Raspberrypi NOOBS in .img file format?

Tags: raspberry-pi

[NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) is officially available to download only in Zip file format and I'm looking source to download in .img file format.

Comment: Once you download the zip file and unzip the file, it will have the .img file.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the .img file is for the case of Raspbian which comes as a zipped .img file. For NOOBS (New Out of Box Software), it does not come as a disk image, all you need to do is "drag and drop" all the unzipped files to the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi Foundation's partners offer SD cards pre-installed with NOOBS. You can try to extract an `.img` from any of them. Apart from this, there is no official `.img` file available to download.

The distribution of NOOBS is different compared to other available (OS) images. All you need to do is grab a copy of the NOOBS zip file, and unpack it onto the root directory of a freshly formatted (FAT) SD card (8GB or larger). On first boot, a list of operating systems that are available to install will be displayed.

Please refer to [this document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md) for more details.